# Get data from angular material-dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I need your help! I need to get a value from 'result'to my external service. But there are some troubles with it, maybe because of async working. How can I get it from my component? My Angular version is 12. This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ModalComponent } from '../modal/modal.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalResultService {

  param!:string 

  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }

  dialogResult(){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent)
    
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

In my external service I want to do something like this

```
update(note: Notation): Observable<Notation> {
    if (this.res.dialogResult())
      return this.http.patch<Notation(`${environment.fbDbUrl}/posts/${note.id}.json`, note);
    return of(this.dNotation)
  }
```

dNotation is some default object

Comment: What kind of troubles? What is your issue?

Comment: My service is implemented to another service. I need to get value from "result" to external service

Comment: Okay but what issue are you exactly encountering? Show us some code that is not working and what you would expect instead.

Comment: What is not working? Have you tried using ngModel inside your dialog to get the value instead? Show us the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return an `Observable` and use async code all the way.

```
dialogResult(): Observable<Boolean> {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent)    
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
}
```

And in your other service:

```
update(note: Notation): Observable<Notation> {
    this.res.dialogResult().pipe(
      mergeMap(result => {
        if(result) { 
          return this.http.patch<Notation(`${environment.fbDbUrl}/posts/${note.id}.json`, note);
        } else {
          return of(this.dNotation);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Note: read RxJs documentation about `mergeMap` to see if it fits your use case. Maybe another operator is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order for the component to be usable as a dialog body, we need to declare it as an entryComponent as well.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.